# How to generate a PDF from a HTML Table?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf, pdf-generation

Here is my code, I have received all the rows but the issue with design not showing properly. Second page mixed with header and 11 th row..

```
  $scope.generatePDF = function () {
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
    // source can be HTML-formatted string, or a reference
    // to an actual DOM element from which the text will be scraped.
    source = $('#div_print')[0];

    // we support special element handlers. Register them with jQuery-style 
    // ID selector for either ID or node name. ("#iAmID", "div", "span" etc.)
    // There is no support for any other type of selectors 
    // (class, of compound) at this time.
    specialElementHandlers = {
        // element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector
        '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
            // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
            return true
        }
    };
    margins = {
        top: 80,
        bottom: 10,
        left: 10,
        width: 800
    };
    // all coords and widths are in jsPDF instance's declared units
    // 'inches' in this case
    pdf.fromHTML(
    source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
    margins.left, // x coord
    margins.top, { // y coord
        'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    },

    function (dispose) {
        // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF 
        //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
        pdf.save('PriceList.pdf');
    }, margins);
}
```

Here I used:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.min.js"></script>  
<script src="../Scripts/Pdf.js"></script>
```

[Here is my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5a0p.png)

Comment: Do you get any console errors? If not, if you put a breakpoint on `pdf.save('PriceList.pdf');` is the `pdf` object populated?

Comment: I don't get any errors